# Create python functions from expression trees

Tags: python, tree, filtering

I'm trying to create collection filters from expression trees (these would be generated from the GUI using wxpython tree controls). I would then use these filters with python's filter(func, iterable) method.

The challenge now is how can I create a function at runtime based on the rules found in the expression tree. An example of how such a function would look is:

```
def filterFunc(element):
    if element == 'Apple' or element == 'Orange' or element == 'Duck':
        return True
    return False
```

The solution I'm currently thinking is to traverse the tree, generate a string containing actual Python code based on the tree contents(probably painful to code), and then call eval() on the resulting string.

Any advice or pointers on what would the correct/pythonic way to solve this would be much appreciated !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that your expression tree is composed of a number of objects, whose type corresponds with what kind of expression it is. Ex. Or, Equals, strings, etc. Something like this:

```
class OrExpression:
    def __init__(self, left, right):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

class EqualsExpression:
    def __init__(self, left, right):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

class Literal:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

class Variable:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

An expression equivalent to your example would look like this:

```
e = OrExpression(
    EqualsExpression(
        Variable("element"),
        Literal("Apple")
    ),
    OrExpression(
        EqualsExpression(
            Variable("element"),
            Literal("Orange")
        ),
        EqualsExpression(
            Variable("element"),
            Literal("Duck")
        )
    )
)
```

You could create a method `eval` for each class that evaluates itself for a given context. Like so:

```
class OrExpression:
    def __init__(self, left, right):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
    def eval(self, variables):
        return self.left.eval(variables) or self.right.eval(variables)

class EqualsExpression:
    def __init__(self, left, right):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
    def eval(self, variables):
        return self.left.eval(variables) == self.right.eval(variables)

class Literal:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def eval(self, variables):
        return self.value

class Variable:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def eval(self, variables):
        return variables[self.name]
```

Then you can call `eval` and supply the context. In your example, you only need to pass in the value of `element`.

```
print e.eval({"element": "Apple"})
print e.eval({"element": "Duck"})
print e.eval({"element": "Banana"})
```

Result:

```
True
True
False
```

But what if, instead, you don't differentiate kinds of expression by type? Suppose your tree is composed of plain old nodes, that identify what kind of expression they are using their `value` attribute. The code is approximately the same, just using a single monolithic switch case, instead of individual `eval` methods.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value=None, *children):
        self.value = value
        self.children = children

def evalTree(t, variables):
    if t.value == "Or":
        return evalTree(t.children[0], variables) or evalTree(t.children[1], variables)
    elif t.value == "Equals":
        return evalTree(t.children[0], variables) == evalTree(t.children[1], variables)
    elif t.value == "Literal":
        return t.children[0].value
    elif t.value == "Variable":
        name = t.children[0].value
    else:
        raise Exception("Unrecognized node type")

t = Node("Or",
    Node("Equals",
        Node("Variable", Node("element")),
        Node("Literal", Node("Apple"))
    ),
    Node("Or",
        Node("Equals",
            Node("Variable", Node("element")),
            Node("Literal", Node("Apple"))
        ),
        Node("Equals",
            Node("Variable", Node("element")),
            Node("Literal", Node("Apple"))
        )
    )
)

print evalTree(t,{"element": "Apple"})
print evalTree(t,{"element": "Duck"})
print evalTree(t,{"element": "Banana"})
```

Result:

```
True
True
False
```

Comment: This is actually rather elegant, and more resilient to future changes than my clumsy solution (your first example).